# Add field values from one array to another (php)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array named `$json` with 47 sub-arrays. Inside those sub-arrays, there is a `[company]` field. 15 of those sub-arrays have an empty `[company]` field.

So, to fill those empty `[company]` fields, I use a website to search for a company name based on the `[mac]` field. The following ugly hack gets the job done:

```
foreach ($json as $key=>$field)
{
    if (empty($field['company'])) 
    {
        $emptyCompany[] = $field['company'];
        $companyFinder = file_get_contents('http://www.adminsub.net/mac-address-finder/'.$field['mac']);
        $html = htmlspecialchars($companyFinder);
        $cutFrom = "www.google.com/search?q=";
        $cutTo = "&quot;";
        $sub = substr($html, strpos($html, $cutFrom) + strlen($cutFrom), strlen($html));
        $newCompany[] = substr($sub, 0, strpos($sub, $cutTo));
    }
}
```

Below are the arrays in question.

Empty company array using `print_r($emptyCompany)`, just for reference:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] => 
    [13] => 
    [14] => 
)
```

New company array using `print_r($newCompany)`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sony Mobile Communications AB
    [1] => Microsoft Corporation
    [2] =>  
    [3] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
    [4] =>  
    [5] => ALPS ERECTORIC CO.,LTD.
    [6] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
    [7] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
    [8] => Nokia Corporation
    [9] => LG Electronics
    [10] => LG Electronics
    [11] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
    [12] =>  
    [13] => LG Electronics
    [14] => LG Electronics
)
```

`$json` array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 640
            [mac] => 00:16:98:B0:12:64
            [company] => T&A Mobile Phones
            [date_seconds] => 1420077635639
            [title] => ALCATEL ONE TOUCH POP C5
            [timestamp] => 1420077691701
            [latitude] => -15.8524528
            [longitude] => -48.9588197
            [altitude] => 764.9000244140625
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -95
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 642
            [mac] => B0:35:8D:F6:95:61
            [company] => Nokia Corporation
            [date_seconds] => 1420077664750
            [title] => 202
            [timestamp] => 1420077783525
            [latitude] => -15.852453
            [longitude] => -48.9588198
            [altitude] => 764.9000244140625
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -92
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 639
            [mac] => B4:52:7E:A2:39:24
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420077631422
            [title] => C2304 BT
            [timestamp] => 1420077875407
            [latitude] => -15.8524667
            [longitude] => -48.9588193
            [altitude] => 762.7999877929688
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -99
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 641
            [mac] => D4:8F:33:B7:02:A4
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420077664483
            [title] => Nokia225
            [timestamp] => 1420077877692
            [latitude] => -15.8524666
            [longitude] => -48.9588192
            [altitude] => 762.7999877929688
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -81
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 637
            [mac] => 76:05:EC:B6:0D:18
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420077584596
            [timestamp] => 1420077947070
            [latitude] => -15.8526392
            [longitude] => -48.9586783
            [altitude] => 766.4000244140625
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -64
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 638
            [mac] => 04:18:0F:F1:62:82
            [company] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
            [date_seconds] => 1420077625693
            [timestamp] => 1420078626690
            [latitude] => -15.8526245
            [longitude] => -48.9586099
            [altitude] => 767.7000122070313
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -97
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 645
            [mac] => 00:1B:FB:84:A6:01
            [company] => Alps Electric Co., Ltd
            [date_seconds] => 1420080593817
            [timestamp] => 1420080593817
            [latitude] => -15.852645
            [longitude] => -48.9585741
            [altitude] => 766.0
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -90
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 647
            [mac] => 68:48:98:9B:C9:E5
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420081331918
            [title] => Reinaldo Luz (Galaxy S
            [timestamp] => 1420081334914
            [latitude] => -15.8526664
            [longitude] => -48.9584509
            [altitude] => 769.9000244140625
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -93
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 646
            [mac] => 18:46:17:34:3D:2A
            [company] => Samsung Electronics
            [date_seconds] => 1420080986423
            [title] => C3222
            [timestamp] => 1420081500612
            [latitude] => -15.8526021
            [longitude] => -48.9586167
            [altitude] => 758.5999755859375
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -89
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 648
            [mac] => 0C:14:20:C2:EF:0E
            [company] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
            [date_seconds] => 1420081774680
            [title] => Samsung S5222
            [timestamp] => 1420081774680
            [latitude] => -15.8525864
            [longitude] => -48.9585792
            [altitude] => 749.5999755859375
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -76
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 649
            [mac] => 00:12:1C:B0:17:11
            [company] => PARROT S.A.
            [date_seconds] => 1420081957160
            [timestamp] => 1420081957160
            [latitude] => -15.8525838
            [longitude] => -48.9585793
            [altitude] => 749.5
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -82
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 651
            [mac] => 60:E1:F8:2E:99:58
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420082126387
            [timestamp] => 1420082132244
            [latitude] => -15.8526099
            [longitude] => -48.958569
            [altitude] => 755.2999877929688
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -93
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 653
            [mac] => E0:75:0A:14:82:B9
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420082598249
            [timestamp] => 1420082632504
            [latitude] => -15.8525498
            [longitude] => -48.9586453
            [altitude] => 763.9000244140625
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -100
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 652
            [mac] => 50:FC:9F:31:FC:95
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420082559412
            [timestamp] => 1420083040325
            [latitude] => -15.8525465
            [longitude] => -48.9586551
            [altitude] => 763.7000122070313
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -74
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 654
            [mac] => 34:C7:31:E4:5B:35
            [company] => ALPS Co,. Ltd.
            [date_seconds] => 1420083215566
            [timestamp] => 1420083215566
            [latitude] => -15.852421
            [longitude] => -48.9586235
            [altitude] => 757.2999877929688
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -97
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 655
            [mac] => 74:5E:1C:6C:26:F7
            [company] => PIONEER CORPORATION
            [date_seconds] => 1420083215735
            [title] => AVH-265BT
            [timestamp] => 1420083256624
            [latitude] => -15.8521723
            [longitude] => -48.958702
            [altitude] => 760.7000122070313
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -75
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 657
            [mac] => 40:BA:61:C3:06:6D
            [company] => Arima Communications Corp.
            [date_seconds] => 1420083274599
            [title] => X350MONTEIRO
            [timestamp] => 1420083274599
            [latitude] => -15.8521477
            [longitude] => -48.9587804
            [altitude] => 759.2000122070313
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -75
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 659
            [mac] => 00:0D:92:0D:C6:41
            [company] => Arima Communication Corporation
            [date_seconds] => 1420083444880
            [timestamp] => 1420083444880
            [latitude] => -15.851529
            [longitude] => -48.9585946
            [altitude] => 741.2000122070313
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -89
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 660
            [mac] => C0:65:99:CA:15:FE
            [company] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
            [date_seconds] => 1420083561134
            [title] => C3222
            [timestamp] => 1420083561134
            [latitude] => -15.8509498
            [longitude] => -48.9583767
            [altitude] => 0.0
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -98
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 661
            [mac] => 10:F9:6F:27:B9:4E
            [company] => LG Electronics
            [date_seconds] => 1420083571135
            [title] => Talis
            [timestamp] => 1420083612114
            [latitude] => -15.8510159
            [longitude] => -48.9583372
            [altitude] => 745.0
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -91
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 663
            [mac] => 6C:2F:2C:14:BE:13
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420083751261
            [title] => Roquia Maria (GT-S5312
            [timestamp] => 1420083751261
            [latitude] => -15.8505985
            [longitude] => -48.9583914
            [altitude] => 751.0
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -96
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 664
            [mac] => 30:76:6F:92:FA:6B
            [company] => LG Electronics
            [date_seconds] => 1420083790225
            [title] => LG-E455f
            [timestamp] => 1420083790225
            [latitude] => -15.8504914
            [longitude] => -48.9583997
            [altitude] => 749.0999755859375
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -94
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 665
            [mac] => 00:0D:18:A1:54:71
            [company] => Mega-Trend Electronics CO., LTD.
            [date_seconds] => 1420083794522
            [timestamp] => 1420083794522
            [latitude] => -15.8504859
            [longitude] => -48.9583969
            [altitude] => 748.7999877929688
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -83
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 667
            [mac] => 24:C6:96:5E:7B:B9
            [company] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
            [date_seconds] => 1420083840328
            [timestamp] => 1420083840577
            [latitude] => -15.8502176
            [longitude] => -48.9585146
            [altitude] => 746.5999755859375
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -91
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 666
            [mac] => 00:54:AF:50:C9:8F
            [company] => Continental Automotive Systems Inc.
            [date_seconds] => 1420083815293
            [timestamp] => 1420083867328
            [latitude] => -15.8501471
            [longitude] => -48.958544
            [altitude] => 749.5999755859375
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -96
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 668
            [mac] => DC:3E:F8:A7:DE:C7
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420083848715
            [title] => Nokia 310
            [timestamp] => 1420083884569
            [latitude] => -15.8500601
            [longitude] => -48.9585936
            [altitude] => 744.0
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -96
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 656
            [mac] => 00:54:AF:50:5A:CE
            [company] => Continental Automotive Systems Inc.
            [date_seconds] => 1420083232134
            [timestamp] => 1420083961168
            [latitude] => -15.8497313
            [longitude] => -48.9585141
            [altitude] => 751.2999877929688
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -90
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 673
            [mac] => 80:50:1B:85:5A:ED
            [company] => Nokia Corporation
            [date_seconds] => 1420084029064
            [timestamp] => 1420084078972
            [latitude] => -15.8495164
            [longitude] => -48.9583397
            [altitude] => 751.7999877929688
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -72
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 671
            [mac] => BC:F5:AC:0B:26:49
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420083954108
            [title] => LG-C397
            [timestamp] => 1420084082109
            [latitude] => -15.8495164
            [longitude] => -48.9583397
            [altitude] => 751.7999877929688
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -95
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 672
            [mac] => 88:C9:D0:6B:C1:AA
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420083990120
            [title] => LG-E467f
            [timestamp] => 1420084082257
            [latitude] => -15.8495164
            [longitude] => -48.9583397
            [altitude] => 751.7999877929688
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -92
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 674
            [mac] => E0:A6:70:1B:CC:AB
            [company] => Nokia Corporation
            [date_seconds] => 1420084204715
            [timestamp] => 1420084204715
            [latitude] => -15.849459
            [longitude] => -48.957572
            [altitude] => 744.5999755859375
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -86
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 675
            [mac] => 08:37:3D:66:1B:13
            [company] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
            [date_seconds] => 1420084275075
            [title] => GT-I8190L
            [timestamp] => 1420084275075
            [latitude] => -15.8496899
            [longitude] => -48.9572679
            [altitude] => 755.5999755859375
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -93
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 676
            [mac] => 78:47:1D:B6:A0:16
            [company] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
            [date_seconds] => 1420084287659
            [title] => Angelica
            [timestamp] => 1420084292776
            [latitude] => -15.8497522
            [longitude] => -48.9572883
            [altitude] => 755.4000244140625
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -98
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 677
            [mac] => C8:AA:21:20:A6:6E
            [company] => Motorola Mobility, LLC.
            [date_seconds] => 1420084455249
            [title] => Motorola EX108
            [timestamp] => 1420084491070
            [latitude] => -15.8502285
            [longitude] => -48.9576278
            [altitude] => 753.2000122070313
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -90
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 670
            [mac] => 58:A2:B5:28:3C:4C
            [company] => LG Electronics
            [date_seconds] => 1420083891600
            [title] => LG-A395
            [timestamp] => 1420084511148
            [latitude] => -15.8502971
            [longitude] => -48.9577257
            [altitude] => 754.5
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -91
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 678
            [mac] => 00:1F:89:88:8C:2E
            [company] => Signalion GmbH
            [date_seconds] => 1420084568312
            [timestamp] => 1420084568312
            [latitude] => -15.8503558
            [longitude] => -48.9577714
            [altitude] => 754.0
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -87
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 679
            [mac] => 10:F9:6F:FF:5A:54
            [company] => LG Electronics
            [date_seconds] => 1420084666382
            [timestamp] => 1420084666382
            [latitude] => -15.8507209
            [longitude] => -48.9580627
            [altitude] => 747.7000122070313
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -99
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 662
            [mac] => 60:A1:0A:6B:7D:C0
            [company] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
            [date_seconds] => 1420083732890
            [title] => Angela
            [timestamp] => 1420084685321
            [latitude] => -15.8507479
            [longitude] => -48.9581244
            [altitude] => 747.2000122070313
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -81
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 680
            [mac] => FC:19:10:5A:19:E8
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420084759306
            [title] => SM-G355M
            [timestamp] => 1420084809467
            [latitude] => -15.8509884
            [longitude] => -48.9583195
            [altitude] => 748.7999877929688
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -93
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 669
            [mac] => 39:2E:EA:30:62:50
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420083878124
            [title] => P200
            [timestamp] => 1420084905369
            [latitude] => -15.8513452
            [longitude] => -48.9586177
            [altitude] => 745.7999877929688
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -92
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 682
            [mac] => F0:5A:09:DC:A4:4A
            [company] => Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
            [date_seconds] => 1420085011925
            [title] => GT-P3100
            [timestamp] => 1420085011925
            [latitude] => -15.8520308
            [longitude] => -48.9589976
            [altitude] => 756.5
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -92
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 681
            [mac] => BC:F5:AC:8A:DB:85
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420084909871
            [title] => LG-A395
            [timestamp] => 1420085043013
            [latitude] => -15.8522648
            [longitude] => -48.9590723
            [altitude] => 759.7000122070313
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -70
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 683
            [mac] => 74:5E:1C:54:B5:3E
            [company] => PIONEER CORPORATION
            [date_seconds] => 1420085184840
            [title] => MVH-X368BT  
            [timestamp] => 1420085184840
            [latitude] => -15.8525656
            [longitude] => -48.9586717
            [altitude] => 761.7000122070313
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -91
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 684
            [mac] => 00:19:C1:99:3D:6F
            [company] => Alps Electric Co., Ltd
            [date_seconds] => 1420085492235
            [timestamp] => 1420085492235
            [latitude] => -15.8526307
            [longitude] => -48.9585812
            [altitude] => 765.4000244140625
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -97
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 685
            [mac] => 00:23:3D:4D:41:07
            [company] => Novero holding B.V.
            [date_seconds] => 1420085591500
            [timestamp] => 1420085591500
            [latitude] => -15.8526308
            [longitude] => -48.9585814
            [altitude] => 765.4000244140625
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -91
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 686
            [mac] => 90:03:B7:CE:7C:64
            [company] => PARROT
            [date_seconds] => 1420087671133
            [title] => AVH-X7580BT
            [timestamp] => 1420089145817
            [latitude] => -15.8527276
            [longitude] => -48.9585511
            [altitude] => 765.5
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -96
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [local_mac] => 98:D6:F7:83:68:39
            [device_type] => 1
            [id] => 644
            [mac] => 48:59:29:5B:5D:89
            [company] => 
            [date_seconds] => 1420078339246
            [title] => LG-A395
            [timestamp] => 1420090390755
            [latitude] => -15.8526706
            [longitude] => -48.9585857
            [altitude] => 764.5
            [provider] => fused
            [rssi] => -92
        )    
)
```

**My question is: How do I add the new company values FROM the `$newCompany` array TO the `$json` array correctly?**. I tried using `push_array()` and `push_merge()` but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the value directly in the loop

```
$json[$key]['company'] = substr($sub, 0, strpos($sub, $cutTo));
```

When this is not possible, make sure your `$newCompany`-Array is indexed with `$key` and then merge the arrays:

```
// Option 1 - use this line in the loop and then loop through the created array
$newCompany[$key] = substr($sub, 0, strpos($sub, $cutTo));

foreach($newCompany as $key => $value){
    $json[$key]['company'] = $value;
}


// Option 2 - use this line in the loop and use array_merge_recursive
$newCompany[$key] = ['company' => substr($sub, 0, strpos($sub, $cutTo))];

array_merge_recursive($json, $newComany);
```

I am not completely sure how array_merge_recursive will handle that. Mae sure to test that before using!

Comment: Thank you. Your first recommendation worked beautifully.